# Get the GroupBox name from the sender

Tags: c#, events, user-interface, groupbox, sender

Is it possible to get the `GroupBox` name(Text Name) from the button's `Click` argument - `Sender`, where the button resides inside the `GroupBox`.

I don't want to use use `GroupBox` instance inside the `button_click()` event.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Parent` property.

```
((Button) sender).Parent.Text
```